# blockchain.info receiving address changes - is it OK to put BTC address on the website?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, payment, websites, receiving

Wallet from blockchain.info change the receiving address from time to time. I guess the rationale is to protect my privacy or something.

In reality I'd be more secure in my head if I had the same BTC address...

Solution to that would be to create own vanity address, but in the meanwhile - is it OK if I publish the address on the website and will it work in 6 months?

**EDIT / UPDATE:** Wish the changing addresses were better explained - https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet - I was quite seriously worried why my address is changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can view addresses by going to Settings -> Addresses, & scroll down to click on Used Addresses.

https://blockchain.info/wallet/#/settings/addresses

Source: https://twitter.com/AskBlockchain/status/857605907915657217

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from blockchain.info because its a wallet.

You should use an address that you have to download to your computer and use a keystore file with password. No one has the keystore file or password so it'll be safe.

Try:
https://bitcoin.org/en/download
and there are many others.

You're using another company and if they go out of business (I doubt blockchain.info would ever) then you may lose your coin.

Comment: I know that address is safe, I'm worried that it constantly changes and I don't even know to see the history of all receiving addresses...

Comment: Theorically speaking, Bitcoin was designed to use 1 address per transaction and not to reuse them. Be it as it may, users always do the opposite to what developers create (trust me, I know). In your case, you may have received a transaction and the system gave you a new address - they don't change randomly.